# How to remove lines from video taken from car rear view camera using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, watermark, video-watermarking

I want to remove reference lines from a video taken from a car rear view camera, as shown in the picture below.

[image: Please refer this image]

I have tried the inpaint method but it's not accurate and very slow in real time video processing. Is there any other technique how I can remove these lines?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://news.developer.nvidia.com/new-ai-imaging-technique-reconstructs-photos-with-realistic-results/):

> Researchers from NVIDIA, led by Guilin Liu, introduced a
>   state-of-the-art deep learning method that can edit images or
>   reconstruct a corrupted image, one that has holes or is missing
>   pixels.

You can use a template image that only contains the lines to remove them from the image, and reconstruct the holes in the image using [the researchers' implementation of the above technology](https://github.com/naoto0804/pytorch-inpainting-with-partial-conv).

Comment: thanks, but i need to perform real time processing, any other solution please !